# Negative power & Chandra's Pyreling

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Scenario:
I control [Cavalcade of Calamity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCavalcade%20of%20Calamity%5d), three [Tin Street Dodger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTin%20Street%20Dodger%5d)s and [Chandra's Pyreling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%27s%5d%2b%5bPyreling%5d) enchanted with [So Tiny](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSo%20Tiny%5d). I have two cards in my graveyard. So now, my Chandra's Pyreling is -1/3. If I get it right, when I attack with all these creatures, Cavalcade's ability triggers four times, and in the result of that Chandra's Pyreling becomes 3/3 creature with double strike until the end of turn. Am I right?

Comment: I believe you mean "negative power," not "negative toughness."

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. From the [complete rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules):

> 107.1b Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero. You can’t choose a negative number, deal negative damage, gain negative life, and so on. **However, it’s possible for a game value, such as a creature’s power, to be less than zero. If a calculation or comparison needs to use a negative value, it does so.** If a calculation that would determine the result of an effect yields a negative number, zero is used instead, unless that effect doubles or sets to a specific value a player’s life total or a creature’s power and/or toughness.
> Example: If a 3/4 creature gets -5/-0, it’s a -2/4 creature. It doesn’t assign damage in combat. Its total power and toughness is 2. Giving it +3/+0 would raise its power to 1.

So a negative power value is NOT treated as zero unless it's going to have a direct effect on the game like dealing damage. All other times (including your example), normal math is used, so 1 (initial power) minus 2 (so tiny) plus 4 ones (triggers) is 3.